# Filter dates using regex

Tags: python, regex, date

There are multiple strings like below

```
trunk.2013.11.13
trunk.2013.11.17
trunk.2013.12.31
trunk.2014.01.05
trunk.2014.01.07
```

Regex to include all strings from dec 2013 will look like this,

```
trunk.2013.12...|trunk.201[^123]......|trunk.20[^01].......
```

Is there some tool/script/library/codereceipe that can help build such regex given date range? Unfortunately it has to be a regex, as it is part of some configuration file. Writing the regex manually for each date is a pain and difficult to get right. Also, an automated tool might generate a better shorter regex instead of the manually written one.

Note:

1. Assume the strings are already valid dates and always appear in a fixed format. There is no need to validate dates in the regex.

Comment: Why not parse the input (as there are valid dates) as dates and do a comparision `>=` with a date from the configuration file?

Comment: Program that reads the configuration file is not in my control. I only write/generate the configuration file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you have to use regex you have to be explicit...

Because dates are increasing, you need at least

- one statements within one month
- two statements within one year
- or three for more than one year.

For the number ranges year, month and day you could use [range-regex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/range-regex) or [RegEx_for_range](http://utilitymill.com/utility/Regex_For_Range). This is may what you are searching for.

Comment: Thanks. That was close. I will try to wrap it on dates

Answer (score 0):

Try with these two regular expressions

## For Dec Month, Every Year 2013 onwards

regExp = r'trunk.20[1-9][3-9].12'
and

## For All Months Beyond that, This is also applicable for all months all year more than 2013.

regExp = r'trunk.20[1-9][3-9].[0[1-9]|[10-12]]'

Note 'trunk.20[1-9][3-9].[0[1-9]|[10-12]]' This will match all your dates, If you need specific dates after dec 2013 then It needs to be changed.

```
>>> import re
>>> regExp = r'trunk.20[1-9][3-9].[0[1-9]|[10-12]]'
>>> srchObj = re.search(regExp,'trunk.2013.11.13')
>>> print srchObj
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x01AE2B80>
>>> srchObj = re.search(regExp,'trunk.2013.11.17')
>>> print srchObj
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x01AE2BB8>
>>> srchObj = re.search(regExp,'trunk.2013.12.31')
>>> print srchObj
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x01AE2B80>
>>> srchObj = re.search(regExp,'trunk.2014.01.05')
>>> print srchObj
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x01AE2BB8>
>>> srchObj = re.search(regExp,'trunk.2014.01.07')
>>> print srchObj
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x01AE2B80>
>>>
```